# what is the best way to convert a gsl_matrix_float to gsl_matrix?

Tags: gsl

What is the best way to convert a gsl_matrix_float to gsl_matrix (double data)? Seems not finding some existing GSL API. Maybe some kind of pointer casting?

Comment: Unless you are limited by the amount of memory, you should start with gsl_matrix and not use floats at all. They are as fast as doubles and casting back of forth can cause you loss of precision.